# webhook with fastapi: I am not getting webhooks with Python

Tags: python, webhooks, fastapi

I am trying to get json data on my localhost. But I am getting a problem with `Request.json`.

*main.py*

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
app = FastAPI()
@app.post("/webhook")
async def get_body(request: Request):
    print(request.json)
    return await request.json()
```

*server.py*

```
import requests
import json

webhook_url = "http://127.0.0.1:4000/webhook"

data = { 'name': 'test data', 
         'Channel URL': 'test url' } # myutube channels


r = requests.post(webhook_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

*output*

```
<function Request.json at 0x7ff2d0a878b0>
```

*expected output*

```
{
  "name": "test data",
  "Channel URL": "test url"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get back a response object from the requests library. You can try to get the json content using `r.json()` method.

See docs:
https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestion, I am trying to change something's in my `main.py` code. If something's change in `server.py`, it will automatically send json data.

Comment: Is the output the result of your print statement in your main.py file ? or is it the returned response by the API call ? If it is the print statement can you try making it `print(request.json())` instead of `print(request.json)`

Comment: I tried with `print(request.json())`, and getting error : `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`